# After Removing SMS & Read Call Log Permission I am still getting Google warning

Tags: android, permissions

According Google Privacy Policy I removed SMS & Call Log Permission from My Manifest file. But my app was rejected after removing the permission and also I am still getting permission warning in play store console.

Comment: add your manifest file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Remove phone state.

Comment: READ_PHONE_STATE is required for me to get the Device ID. without that i cant login to my app.

Comment: accepted my edit question. I add your gradle file in your question.

Comment: [Please check if this is the issue, and find the accepted solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391621/google-play-services-sms-and-call-logs-permission-issue/55392826#55392826)

Answer (score 0):

READ_PHONE_STATE is not in the updated [dangerous policy list](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/). Your problem can be causing from a previous apk, which is still active in some channels. You can see the list of previously declared permissions while uploading the new apk. Check if [this solves your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391621/google-play-services-sms-and-call-logs-permission-issue/55392826#55392826). You need to make sure all active apks in all channels are updated to the apk without the dangerous permissions.